Woodin cardinal and forcing
I am going through Larson's The Stationary Tower, Theorem 1.5.12, which states that if $\delta$ is Woodin then every tree can be made weakly homogeneous by forcing with $\text{Coll}(\omega,\alpha)$ for $\alpha<\delta$. We fix $T$ to be on $\omega\times\delta$, $S=\{\xi<\delta:\xi\text{ is $<\delta-T-$strong}\}$, and $\kappa$ to be $<-\delta-(T,S)-$strong, forcing over $\text{Coll}(\omega,2^{2^\kappa})$. There is a line saying "fix $\alpha<\delta$ and $\xi\in S\setminus(\max\{\alpha,\kappa\}+1)$ and $\xi<\lambda<\delta$ so that every condition forces $p[T]=p[T\cap V_\lambda]$", but I don't see immediately why it's possible to find such $\lambda$. I suspect it might only use some simple property like inaccessible, but I can't see the exact argument behind it.

This is just a general fact, as you suspect:

Suppose $\mathrm{cof}(\delta)>2^\omega$ and $T$ is a tree on $\omega\times\delta$. Then there is some $\lambda<\delta$ with $p[T]=p[T\cap (\omega\times\lambda)^{<\omega}]$.

You may want to try to prove this yourself, the specific assumption on $\mathrm{cof}(\delta)$ here should give you some hint!
Otherwise, here is the argument:

For each $x\in p[T]$, by definition there is some $\vec\xi\in \delta^\omega$ with $(x, \vec \xi)\in [T]$, so $\sup \xi<\delta$ as $\delta$ has uncountable cofinality. So there is some minmal $\lambda_x<\delta$ with $x\in p[T\cap(\omega\times\lambda_x)^{<\omega}]$. We can now take $\lambda=\sup_{x\in\omega^\omega}\lambda_x$ which is still below $\delta$ by our assumption on $\delta$.

For your specific situation, simply note that $\delta$ remains inaccessible (even Woodin) in the extension by the small forcing $\mathrm{Coll}(\omega,2^{2^\kappa})$.

Aha, the cofinality given is indeed a really helpful hint. Thank you for the response!
